# Regex for matching Table.Column in a list of columns of different tables

Tags: regex

I want to isolate all `CLIENT.xxxx` in this string:

```
CLIENT.TEST,Toto.test,Test.Test,CLIENT.NOM,
Zozo.zaza,CLIENT.Machin,Truc.Chose,Truc.tralala,
```

I use this regular expression: `CLIENT\..*[\,\)]`. But, as you can see at https://regex101.com/r/LKD50F/1 not only CLIENT.xxxx match the expression but also Toto.test, Test.test, and so on.

How can I modify my regexp to match only CLIENT.xxxx ?

Comment: `CLIENT\.\w+[\,\)]` ?

Comment: `.*` is greedy; you should make it lazy (i.e., `.*?`). Additionally, `,` doesn't need to be escaped and `)` inside a character class also doesn't need to be escaped. So, you could just use `[,)]`. One more thing, you might want to throw a `\b` before `CLIENT` to avoid matching something like "MULTICLIENT", for example.

Comment: @41686d6564 your anwser is the best one for me, especially for \b tip, the explanation of question mark to use lazy and the tip about not espacing inside []. So you can convert your comment into anwser and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `CLIENT\.\w+[\,\)]`

[regex-demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC5qtV/1)